# Generic function to serialize 'record' to xml in postgresql

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql

I try to create postgresql function wich should serialize some abstract record to xml. Something like this: `to_xml(in item record, out xml text)`

But postgres didn't allow to use record as input parameter type. So I tried to use built-in function `query_to_xml`. It accept query and qrite query's result to xml. But it works only on `select` queries (this function is non-volatile).

Is there any way to create such generic function? It shouldn't be used only plpgsql or sql languages, C is also acceptable.

Update:
Output XML should look like this:

```
<row>
  <first_column_name>value</first_column_name>
  <second_column_name>value</second_column_name>
  <third_column_name>value</third_column_name>
  ...
</row>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of item and xml ?

Comment: I added example of output xml. Item should be any row type. So this function must accept something like any table's record and serialize it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this :

```
select xmlagg(CAST (row as XML)) from 
(SELECT
  xmlelement(
    name row,
    xmlconcat(
      xmlelement(name first_column_name, column1),
      xmlelement(name second_column_name, column2)
      ...
    )
  ) as row
  FROM your_table) as t
```

Comment: I'm not sure it work as I want. Main problem is in fact that function didn't know what kind of record it will have in input parameter. Thereby we didn't know names and count of columns.

Comment: I don't think that's possible to iterate a `record` fields.

Comment: But then how [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html) works? It is possible to create hstore from `record` type.